# can not create src/test/java module jar consistently using maven pom with eclipse

Tags: java, maven, jar

can not create src/test/java module jar consistently using maven pom with eclipse goal

This is my pom file:when i run using eclipse by **runconfig-->In goals if i enter jar:test-jar** and run it creates SFDCSearchSuite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar in my target folder which contains all test module classes **but some times it creating the jar but that does not contains any classes.**

if i run **compile assembly:single** in goals it creates SFDCSearchSuite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar with all **src/main/java** classes every time.

what can i do to create test SFDCSearchSuite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar consistently with all test module classes.

can any one please post me the solution ,thank you

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SFDCSearchSuite</groupId>
<artifactId>SFDCSearchSuite</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.42.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.42.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.package.ClasseName</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins> <!-- This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. 
                It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-compiler-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.3.2,]
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Why do you exclude `src/main/java` and ´src/test/java` from resources? This is by default the case. Why not calling Maven simply by `mvn clean package`? Why calling `mvn compile assembly:singe` which does not make sense.

Comment: i dont want to run test methods at the time of jar creation that is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got answer:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests

Add this in your pom.xml

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```